# Change font of the virtual terminal in Fedora

Tags: terminal, fonts, fedora

Typically, I can change the terminal's font via `Edit->Preference->General` and pick a font.

But my problem is, the fonts available in the `Preference->General` is too limited, the font that I like is not in them.

So, how can I add my favorite font to the available ones in Fedora?

Answer (score 0):

You can add additional font files under /usr/share/fonts .